# How to recollect miner in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I was using miner from IC2 mod in Minecraft, but I am unable to recollect it. I try to recollect it using pickaxe, but whenever I do this, I only get back machine block and nothing else.

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: the above problem is solved but now my minecraft  is hanging too much its fps drops to 1 or 2 and sometimes even stop but on the other hand other worlds are working totally fine can anyone tell me what is going on

Thanks

Akash

Answer (score 4):

like many other machines in IC2 the tool to recover it is the wrench built with 6 bronze ingots in a Y shape. there is still a chance that you will lose the machine though

you can upgrade it to an electric wrench with a circuit and a battery, pressing the "mode" key (defaults to m) and right clicking it will switch it over to lossless mode which requires a lot more energy per pick-up.